# Number of $O_K$-submodules of given index (or given elementary divisors)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K / \mathbb{Q}$ be any number field, and $O_K$ its ring of integers. Consider the $O_K$- submodule $M := O_K^d = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_d):x_i \in O_K\}$, and choose integral ideals $I_1 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq I_d$. Now the question is: how many distinct $O_K$-submodules $N$ does $M$ have such that $M/N \cong O_K/I_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus O_K/I_d$?

This is probably elementary, but stripped of all the conveniences I have in case $K=\mathbb{Q}$, I am not sure how to proceed without invoking too much theory.